# Каким плагином maven запустить *.bat

Tags: maven

Смотрел по exec-maven-plugin:exec, maven-antrun-plugin:run.
Antrun, по субъективным впечатлениям, - костыль. Exec-maven-plugin я настроить нормально не могу (скиньте конфиг, у кого есть).

Может есть еще плагины, более "целевые", что ли?

Comment: А что делает ваш bat в плане сборки?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, конкретно сейчас запускает app-сервер в лице tomcat, ну и стопит его. Т.е. сначала стопит сервер, билдит приложение, запускает сервер. Как то так. Я смотрел на org.apache.tomcat.maven, но если другой сервер приложений будет? Да и вопрос у меня уже возник, и свербит. Должно же быть простое решение

Comment: А зачем в процессе сборки вы запускаете сервер?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, автоматизировать пересборку. Это родительский pom будет: остановить сервер, почистить приложение, установить приложение, запустить сервер. Сейчас останавливаю и запускаю руками. Неудобно)

Comment: вы используете не правильный инструмент. Maven предназначен для сборки проектов, но не для разворачивания инфраструктуры. Используя bat файлы вы теряете переносимость. На unix системе будет сложно собрать ваш проект. Maven может запустить сервер, на пример для тестирования и для этого и есть плагины. Но разворачивать приложение он не должен.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, я и согласен и нет. Запускать на прямую окружение средством сборки - плохой тон. Я понял и поддерживаю. Организация полного жизненного цикла redeploy-я приложения, средствами приложения обеспечения жизненного цикла - вполне логичный запрос. Я к тому, что должен быть какой то плагин, инкапсулирующий в себе платформу и обеспечивающий переносимость простыми настройками?

Comment: не логичный. Так как для этого есть специальные инструменты. Процесс разработки и процесс развертывания - это сильно разные процессы. Выполняются разными людьми. Разными инструментами.

Comment: Я Вас понял. Спасибо за консультацию. Вопрос оставлю, вдруг кому будет полезен.

Comment: без ответа он вряд ли будет полезен.

Comment: ответите развернуто? Я отмечу. Для меня комментарии полезней итогового ответа сейчас)

Comment: у вас вопрос такой, что я не могу ответить. Так как ответ - "не надо так делать" - это не ответ на вопрос "каким плагином".